# How to edit gaming videos for youtube with blender?

Tags: video, edit-mode

someone told me that blender was good for editing youtube videos, but had a steep learning curve. I've looked for tutorials online, but most of them seem outdated, from a year or two ago. Could anyone possibly help me or explain how to use it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: To make better use of this site please try to make more focused questions. As it stands your question will be closed for being too broad. Please read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask. If you are just starting to use blender please refer to the resources listed on this page: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender

Answer (score 1):

Blender has a VERY steep learning curve when it comes to video editing. You should have some basic knowledge of blender before editing videos. But I have found this good tutorial, it should be easy for beginners, and it's up-to-date.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=42AQ_EtRVq4

If blender is too difficult I would recommend Kdenlive.